# GridLayout doesn't work with BoxInsetLayout

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I'm trying to put a GridLayout of TextViews in a BoxInsetLayout so that the TextViews will stretch to fit the BoxInset Layout. What actually happens is that the TextViews ignore the BoxInsetLayout and fill the entire screen, round or rectangular. 
Here's my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:columnCount="9"
    android:rowCount="3">

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="5"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="6"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="7"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="8"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="4"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="5"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="6"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="7"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="8"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="4"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="5"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="6"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="7"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="8"/>

</GridLayout>
```

How can I space elements in a BoxInsetLayout?

Comment: set TextView  width and hight and remove  this line app:layout_box="all"

Comment: This still doesn't let the views adhere to the box inset layout, they are still being cut off by the corners on round devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So adding app:layout_box="all" to my gridlayout fixed it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:columnCount="9"
    android:rowCount="3"
    app:layout_box="all">

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="5"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="6"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="7"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="8"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="4"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="5"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="6"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="7"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="8"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="4"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="5"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="6"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="7"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="8"/>

</GridLayout>
```